# Webcam input sent to pyvirtualcam is blue(using pyvirtualcam and opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am trying to get input from my webcam using OpenCv and send it to a virtual camera using pyvirtualcam. For some reason when my webcam is displayed it gives it a blue filter. When i display my webcam without sending it to virtual camera there is no filter and everything works well.

```
import pyvirtualcam
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=20) as cam:
    while True:
        ret_val, frame = cap.read()

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1280, 720), interpolation=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
        # cv2.imshow('my webcam', frame)
        cam.send(frame)
        cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break  # esc to quit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Be aware that OpenCV creates, uses, expects and sends images in BGR order, unlike just about every other piece of software in the world where RGB is the norm. Get used to using `cv2.cvtColor(... cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`.

Comment: Thank you, everything works fine now @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV uses BGR as pixel format. pyvirtualcam expects RGB by default, but it supports BGR as well:

```
fmt = pyvirtualcam.PixelFormat.BGR
with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=20, fmt=fmt) as cam:
```